# Extension method on type

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, extension-methods

Is there a way to create an extension method for an type ? I only seem to be able to create them for instances.

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static string Test(this string s)
    {
        return "test";
    }
}

public class Test
{
    static void TestIt()
    {
        string.Test();  // won't compile

        string s = null;
        s.Test();
    }
}
```

Comment: Dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/866921/static-extension-methods

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Extension methods can only be created for instances

Answer (score 2):

No. Extension methods are only for instances. In other words, it is not possible to have static extension methods.

Comment: Well, technically all extension methods are static... but I see your point ;)

Answer (score 0):

Right answer: No. Extension methods is methods for instances of some class.

You can have more information from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)