# Make Extension method on base class .NET

Tags: .net, extension-methods

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Static extension methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866921/static-extension-methods)

So I know that Extension methods are for object instances only as in doing

```
public static string stringBig(this string inString) {
     return inString.ToUpper();
}
```

Only works for an instance of `string`

However I am trying to make something that function like `Double.TryParse` so that I don't have to do

```
Double myDouble = someOtherDouble.DoubleParseDifferent("4.324802348203498");
```

I'd like to be able to do something like

```
Double myDouble = Double.DoubleParseDifferent(someRandomString);
```

Now I know that I can't actually do this so what would be some alternative methods or ways I could approach this.

Comment: Possible dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/866921/static-extension-methods

Comment: @Brook yes it is a dupe, I looked forever and didn't find that question. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only possible *alternative* way for implementing `TryParse` I can think of (since what you're asking for is not possible) would be creating a normal static method, but returning a *nullable*.

```
public static double? TryParseEx(string value) { /* new improved parse code here */ }

var result = TryParseEx("1234.56");
```

That way you would not need a output parameter like the normal `TryParse`...

If `!result.HasValue`, then the parse was not successful. Otherwise, just read the `result.Value` property to get the parsed result.

Comment: hmmm this may be the style of thought I may go for doing this. I know what I was asking for wasn't possible which is why I wanted some other way.

Answer (score 3):

You can make a class with a similar name:

```
static class MyDouble { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're adding a string parsing method, why not add an extension to string

```
public static Double ParseDifferent( this string inString) {
     return ...
}
```

Comment: It was all just example typeage, but like Double.Parse

Comment: Still, adding a Parse method to the source type makes sense. Otherwise your own static MyDouble class as @SLaks mentions is the best bet.