# Is it possible to create Static extension Methods

Tags: c#

Is it possible to create extention methods that will be static.

Comment: just type extension method tutorial in google.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Static extension methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/866921/static-extension-methods)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, all extension methods are static - but if you mean methods which can be called as if they were static methods on a different type, the answer is no. Extension methods only "pretend" to be *instance* methods on the extended type.