# c# extend String Class with static method

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I was wondering if there is a way to extend the string class with a method called GenerateRandom() which generates a random string.
Maybe this would look like

```
string.CreateRandom();
```

As I have read there is no way than creating an instance of a string and then calling the extension method. Maybe there is one and you know it.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can't add extension method to a static class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't.

For more information, and an explanation, see these earlier questions:

- [Can I add extension methods to an existing static class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249222/can-i-add-extension-methods-to-an-existing-static-class)
- [Static extension methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866921/static-extension-methods)
- [Why aren't C# static class extension methods supported?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909156/why-arent-c-sharp-static-class-extension-methods-supported/)

Comment: @Daniel One of the C# language designers [gave an explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4914207/590382) back in 2011, I don't know how the rationale will have changed since.

_P.S_ If this answered your question, don't forget to [upvote & mark an answer as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

The same question was asked here: [Static extension methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866921/static-extension-methods)

You can also read there, why you cannot do that.