# random enum value for a generic enum type extension method

Tags: c#, enums, extension-methods

Id like to write an extension method for *any Enum* that returns a random value from that enum, currently ive got this:

```cs
class Monster
{
    public enum presets
    {
     //some values
    }
    presets p = presets.randomEnum();
}
public static class Extensions
{
        public static T randomEnum<T>(this T en) where T : struct , IConvertible , IEnumerable<Enum>
        {
            if (!typeof(T).IsEnum) { throw new Exception("random enum variable is not an enum"); }
            Array values = en.ToArray();
            return (T)values.GetValue(Random.Next(values.Length));
        }
}
```

but when i do `presets.randomEnum()`  Visual Studio 19 tells me that  `Error   CS0117  'Monster.presets' does not contain a definition for 'randomEnum'`

NOTE: i had to do ALOT of googling for that ext method so if theres an easier way that i missed or just didn't think of, id greatly appreciate it

Comment: You can't have a static extension method... They just don't exist.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Static extension methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866921/static-extension-methods)

Comment: I like your question. I am interested why you wrote a function to return a random enum value. Mind to explain what's the purpose of doing it?

Comment: @Sweeper "*You can't have a static extension method.*" - Please explain ?

Comment: @TheGeneral Of course the method declaration is marked "static", in case you misunderstood. :-)  See the answer linked in Martheen's comment. I meant that.

Comment: @hiew1 The general gist is that im creating an object with some enum attributes with random values, and as part of that generation, other enums are involved that i also want random values for so i figured it was a good idea to write a function that takes *any* enum and returns a random value from it. ill be honest im very new to this and its melting my brain so if ive explained that badly i do apologize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extension method must be defined at the top of the class (i.e. inside of a namespace but not in another class).  Also, you can't have that IEnumerable constraint on it, it is too much.  This works for me:

```
 public enum Presets
    {
        Test,
        Test2
    }


    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static T RandomEnum<T>(this T en) where T : struct, IConvertible
        {
            if (!typeof(T).IsEnum) { throw new Exception("random enum variable is not an enum"); }

            var random = new Random();
            var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(T));
            return (T)values.GetValue(random.Next(values.Length));
        }
    }
```

Comment: "Both the Enum and the extension method must be defined at the top of the class" - not true. "(i.e. inside of a namespace but not in another class)." - does not relate to the first part of the  sentence.

Comment: Did you also try this using the OP's code: `presets p = presets.randomEnum();`?

Comment: `Random` is also best defined as `[System.ThreadStatic] private static Random __random = new Random();`.

Answer (score 0):

Your extension method looks fine (I did not test, I am on my mobile), but your templating is not quite right. You have too many constraints.

You are basically saying that..

1. By putting `where T : struct` you are saying the argument must be a non-nullable type (enum's are not nullable, good here..)
2. `where T: IConvertible`The argument must implement the `IConvertible` interface (`enum` implements `IConvertible`.  Good here)
3. `where T : IEnumerable<enum>` It does not appear that your enum is explicitly implementing the `IEnumerable` interface, and it doesn't implement it by default - it doesn't meet the parameter requirements that you have imposed upon your method.

**Edit**: I recommend that you remove the `IEnumerable<enum>` constraints as it is unnecessary.

See enum:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum?view=netcore-3.1

See Constraints on Type Parameters: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters

Answer (score 0):

I have adapted the code to be used in Unity:

```
public static class RandomUtils
{
    public static T GetRandomEnumValue<T>() where T : Enum
    {
        var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(T));
        var index = Random.Range(0, values.Length);
        return (T) values.GetValue(index);
    }
}
```

Thank you.