# Static property injection to native Classes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying add variety to Color class for example:

```
Color c = Color.clearWhite;  //Should return RGBA (1, 1, 1, 0).
```

or

```
Color y = Color.trueYellow;  //Should return RGBA(1,1,0,1).
```

etc.

is there a way to implement this?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean add it to `System.Drawing.Color` ? If so you can't, that is not code you can modify.

Comment: No. You can create your own `MyColor` class, with its own static properties of your choosing, however.

Comment: Closest you can get to this kind of syntax ATM is to create extension methods on the `System.Drawing.Color` and then invoke it like this: `default(Color).TrueYellow()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Static extension methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866921/static-extension-methods)

Comment: @Thomas: Color is a struct, not a static class. It is possible the way Dusan suggests.

Comment: @Palle Due: This is still not an injection of a static property, but creation of an instance and calling a method on it.

Comment: @Igor I'm pretty sure OP is referring to [`UnityEngine.Color`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.html) hence the tag for `unity3d` ;)

Comment: @Dusan same as above comment ;) .. to create a default instance and then fill in different values for the fields in the extension method sounds a valid solution. Questionable though why not simply instantiate it with the correct values right away or create a static readonly field in some other static class ^^

Comment: @Thomas: Sorry, didn't follow the link.I read the title as being about static classes. My bad.